# Windows 11 disk will only boot when Windows 10 disk is also present

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-11

I have a laptop which came with a small NVME SSD with windows 10. I later added a second, larger, NVME SSD and installed Windows 11, which works fine as a dual boot machine. However, when I remove the original small SDD with a view to fitting a larger disk (for Linux, to dual boot Linux and Windows 11), the computer will not boot.
Looking at disk manager, Disk 0 has an EFI partition and Disk 1 does not which I assume is the issue. So when I remove the small SSD (Disk 0) there is no EFI present for the BIOS.

So I think I need to add an EFI partition to Disk 1 (the Windows 11 disk) and make Windows 11 on Disk 1 bootable. What is the best way to do this? Can I do it while already running the Windows 11 on Disk 1 itself?

Comment: Sounds about right. The Windows bootloader was on the first drive you had, that drive updated the bootloader to allow dual boot to the 2nd drive. Now that the first drive is removed, the computer doesn't have a bootloader. Personally, I would just reinstall everything, but you'll have to get into a partition editor change up the 2nd drive partition, and then copy the data from the 1st drive (not the OS partition, which should be the biggest one) to the 2nd drive. And then hope that loads, if it doesn't at that point you'll have to run the Windows repair tools to fix the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this (from Windows 11) by following Method 2 on this link:

https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/missing-efi-partition-windows-10.html

**Step 1.** Boot your computer from a Windows installation disc or recovery disk. Press Shift+F10 in the setup to enter command prompt window.

**Step 2.** Run the commands below to shrink a partition to get unallocated space.

```
Diskpart

List disk

Select disk X (X represents the disk number of the disk that needs an EFI partition)

List partition

Select partition N (N represents the partition number of the partition that needs shrinking)

Shrink desired=500 (shrink the partition by 500MB)
```

[image]

**Step 3.** Then you can create an EFI partition using unallocated space with the command below:

```
create partition efi​

format fs=fat32 quick

assign letter=Y​ exit​ (exit diskpart.exe)
```

[image]

**Step 4.** After those two partitions have been successfully created, use the commands below to install the boot loader and other applications needed.

```
bcdboot C:\windows /s Y:
```

[image]